# Properties of converging succession of functionals

Tags: sequences-and-series, operator-algebras, ergodic-theory, von-neumann-algebras, irreducible-representation

Given a sequence of functionals $(\omega_n)_{n \in \mathcal{N}}$ on a Von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{W}$ converging to $\omega$, I have the following doubts:

1. Is it true that $\omega_n$ is pure $\forall n \in \mathcal{N} \iff \omega$ is pure?
2. Given G group, is it true that $\omega_n$ is G-invariant $\forall n \in \mathcal{N} \iff \omega$ is G-invariant?

Comment: Converging in what topology? Norm, weak$^\ast$? For the second question, do you mean $G$ acts on $\mathcal{W}$? And, of course, the leftward directions of both questions are clearly false. I assume you’re really only asking about the forward direction?

Comment: @DavidGao I did not specify the topology because I would like to understand if there is any difference in the answers. So, please feel free to answer something like "If norm topology, then the answer is xxx. However, if not, the answer is yyy". That would be much appreciated. About the group, the answer to your question is yes. About the direction, I am interested in both. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leftward directions of both questions are easily seen to be false, regardless of topology. For example, set $\mathcal{W} = \mathbb{M}_2$. Then the states represented by density matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 1-\frac{1}{n} & 0\\ 0 & \frac{1}{n}\end{pmatrix}$ are not pure, but they converge in norm to the pure state represented by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Similarly, $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{M}_2$ by sending the generator to the automorphism given by conjugation by $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Then the states represented by $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n} & 0\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\end{pmatrix}$ are not $G$-invariant, but they converge in norm to the state represented by $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$, which is $G$-invariant.

The forward direction of the second question is true, regardless of topology. This is because $\omega \mapsto \omega(g^{-1}x) - \omega(x) \in \mathbb{C}$ is continuous in the weak$^\ast$ topology (and therefore also norm topology), so the collection of functionals such that $\omega(g^{-1}x) = \omega(x)$ for each fixed $g \in G$ and $x \in \mathcal{W}$ is closed. Since $\omega$ being $G$-invariant simply means the above holds for all $g$ and $x$, the collection of $G$-invariant functionals is an intersection of closed sets, whence closed itself.

I don’t know the full answer to the forward direction of the first question, but here are some partial answers and thoughts: the claim is true, regardless of topology, if $\mathcal{W}$ is finite-dimensional, since then pure states are simply vector spaces on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, so the space of pure states is compact. It is also true, regardless of topology, if $\mathcal{W}$ is abelian, since then pure states are multiplicative states and the space of pure states is the Gelfand spectrum of $\mathcal{W}$, which is weak$^\ast$ compact (and therefore also norm closed).

In case $\mathcal{W}$ is neither abelian nor finite-dimensional, the following is “sort of” a counterexample for the statement with the weak$^\ast$ topology. Let $\mathcal{W} = B(\ell^2)$. Recall that a pure state on $B(\ell^2)$ must be either a vector state or evaluates to zero on compact operators $K(\ell^2)$. Let $\omega_n$ be the vector states associated to the unit vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1 + e_n)$ and let $\omega$ be a weak$^\ast$ cluster point of $\omega_n$. Then one easily observes that $\omega$ restricts to the functional $\frac{1}{2} e_1 \otimes e_1$ on $K(\ell^2)$, which is not a vector state, nor zero, whence $\omega$ cannot be pure.

This is only “sort of” a counterexample because $\omega$ is only a weak$^\ast$ cluster point, and therefore an ultralimit of the sequence $(\omega_n)$. I’m not sure this issue can be resolved (or that it should), since the space of states under weak$^\ast$ topology is not first-countable for infinite-dimensional vNa’s, so the topology is not really captured by limits of sequences.

I don’t know about the case for norm topology, but there’s probably not many nontrivial limits of sequences of pure states in the norm topology to begin with, so I wouldn’t be surprised if the answer is true in that case.